# Relationships Between Tables in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, relationship

I'm new in DataBases at all and have some difficulties with setting relationships between 3 tables in MS Access 2013.

The idea is that I have a table with accounts info, a table with calls related to this accounts and also one table with all the possible call responses. I tried different combinations between them but nothing works.

- 1st table - Accounts : AccountID(PK)  | AccountName | Language | Country | Email
- 2nd table - Calls    : CallID(PK)     | Account     | Response | Comment | Date
- 3rd table - Responses: ResponseID(PK) | Response

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'relationship'? Do you want to set the Primary Keys with Foreign Keys in other tables?

Comment: I think I have the idea of FK and PK (if not please correct me), but I mean the relationships between the different fields. For example: (1st table)AccountID- (2nd table)Account: one to many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a table, it usually has a Primary Key field that is the main index of the table. In order for you to connect it with other tables, you usually do that by setting Foreign Key on the other table.

Let's say you have your `Accounts` table, and it has `AccountID` field as Primary Key. This field is unique (meaning no duplicate value for this field).

Now, you have the other table called `Calls` and you have a Foreign Key field called `AccountID` there, which points to the `Accounts` table.

Essentially you have `Accounts` with the following data:

```
AccountID| AccountName | Language | Country | Email
```

---

```
  1      | FirstName   | EN       | US      | some@email.com
  2      | SecondName  | EN       | US      | some@email.com
```

Now you have the other table `Calls` with **Many** calls

```
CallID(PK) | AccountID(FK) | ResponseID(FK) | Comment   | Date
```

---

```
  1        | 1             | 1              | a comment | 26/10
  2        | 1             | 1              | a comment | 26/10
  3        | 2             | 3              | a comment | 26/10
  4        | 2             | 3              | a comment | 26/10
```

You can see the One to Many relationship: One accountID (in my example AccountID=1) to Many Calls (in my example 2 rows with AccountID=1 as foreign keys, rows 1 & 2) and AccountID=2 has also 2 rows of Calls (rows 3 and 4)

Same goes for the `Responses` table

Comment: That's great, it will work perfectly for me but when I try to create this relationship (between tables Accounts and Calls), I got error message "Relationship must be on the same number of fields with the same data types". I check both data types and they are "Number". Also, let me mention that Calls table is empty at the moment. And the last thing, what can I do if I want to enter an account in Calls table, not by number, but account name.

Comment: The field in calls should be of a Long-Integer type, and the PK field in Accounts should be of a AutoNumber type

Comment: Thank you leonid, I think I understand the concept and everything works fine now. There is one more thing I'm facing atm. I wonder how can make when enter a new entity in 'Calls' table, not to use the AccountID, but the names of the accounts (reason: its easier to work with names instead of numbers) and to keep the current relation as well?

Comment: It depends on the SQL query you make, if you join the two tables (for example, to bring all data for AccountID=1, you will also get the field `count` of table Calls. (just look for Joins in access)

Answer (score 0):

Using this table structure:

```
Accounts : AccountID(PK) | AccountName | Language | Country | Email 
Calls    : CallID(PK) | AccountID(FK) | ResponseID(FK) | Comment | Date
Responses: ResponseID(PK) | Response
```

- Accounts.AccountID is referenced by Calls.AccountID. 1:n – many calls for one account possible, but each call concerns just one account.
- Responses.ResponseID is referenced by Calls.ResponseID. 1:n – many calls can get the same response from the prepared set, but each call gets exactly one of them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanations Palec, +1. I handle with that thanks to you guys, but now I have new "mountain to climb". Please check my comment under leonid's answer for more details about it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To actually *define* the Relationships in Access, open the Relationships window...

[image: Relationships.png]

... then follow the detailed instructions here:

[How to define relationships between tables in an Access database](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304466)